# Cast Sum IF mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

Hi I am a beginner in mysql this is my query for getting the sum but somehow the calculation is not right. If anything could enlighten me maybe it is wrong

```
SUM(CAST(IF(r.sum_total_of_booking IS NULL, '0', r.sum_total_of_booking) AS DECIMAL(10,2)))
```

Comment: What type does sum_total_of_booking column have?

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: it is a long text but it is if I used the query I will get whole number with two decimal places

Answer (score 1):

1) Please use appropriate NUMERIC column type for sum_total_of_booking column in table r. If sum_total_of_booking column type is actually numeric then just skip to the next point of mine:

2) '0' is not a number. It's a string. 
Here you're trying to SUM all values of (Casting Undefined column value (aka NULL) into string '0', and then try to cast it as DECIMAL, which also triggers internally string to number conversion attempt)

Instead you should either:

```
SELECT SUM(r.sum_total_of_booking) 
WHERE r.sum_total_of_booking IS NOT NULL [AND <the rest of conditions>];
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(IF(r.sum_total_of_booking IS NULL, 0.00, r.sum_total_of_booking))
```

but this makes no sense what so ever due to **a** above

Either way always try to avoid mismatching data types and column definitions, as well as avoid casting or automatic conversion (domne silently) when numeric value is fed as string into mathematical equation or aggregation function.